# How to turn any mesh into its bounding box

Tags: mesh, transforms

I have a scene and I want to turn it into a blockout scene for presentational purposes. I want to turn every mesh into a box or a block model. Is there any way to achieve this? Scripts are also welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bmesh script**

Quick, n  dirty little bmesh script to do this. For all mesh objects in the screen replace the mesh with the box created from the eight corners of the bounding box.

- I've used the convex hull operator which produces a triangulated
  mesh.
- Current version replaces mesh with hull.
- As always save before, and / or test on a copy.

script

```
import bpy
import bmesh
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
bm = bmesh.new()
mesh_obs = [o for o in scene.objects if o.type == 'MESH']
for ob in mesh_obs:
    me = ob.data 
    #me = ob.data.copy() # create a copy

    verts = [bm.verts.new(b) for b in ob.bound_box]
    bmesh.ops.convex_hull(bm, input=verts)
    bm.to_mesh(me)
    ob.data = me # needed if copy
    bm.clear()
bm.free()
```

Comment: I'll change it to keep the original mesh! But thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can select Bounding box in Viewport Shading setting:

[image]

This option displays all objects as it's Bounding boxes

Comment: No. I don't want it to be for the viewport only. I want to actually deform the mesh into it's bounding box

Comment: Do you want to render it? Do you know, that you can render OpenGL of current viewport?